# Bash command to print even number columns from multiple files

Tags: awk

I have files `t_1.24/data.dat, t_2.48/data.dat, t_3.72/data.dat ...` and each file have two columns. I want to grep the 2nd columns of each file and put them together column by column. I know I can paste them together and do  `awk '{print $2, $4, ..., $2*n}`, but since I have a large number of files, it's obvious not a good way to do it and I believe there are much better solutions. Could anyone give some suggestions to solve this?
Edited: In my case, the files have the same number of lines and each column is separated by space without header. For example, if t_10.48/data.dat is:

```
 9.10000000e+00   -1.14092155e-03
 9.10023800e+00   -1.14131197e-03
 9.10047601e+00   -1.14171327e-03
 9.10071401e+00   -1.14212571e-03
```

t_2.14/data.dat is:

```
 9.10000000e+00   -1.09822747e-03
 9.10023800e+00   -1.09833529e-03
 9.10047601e+00   -1.09844835e-03
 9.10071401e+00   -1.09856643e-03
```

what I want is :

```
 -1.09822747e-03  -1.14092155e-03  
 -1.09833529e-03  -1.14131197e-03  
 -1.09844835e-03  -1.14171327e-03  
 -1.09856643e-03  -1.14212571e-03
```

And I do need to paste them in the order of original file name (eg. t_2.48 has to be before t_10.48).

Comment: If the files can have different numbers of rows then include such cases in your example. Also show if the output columns should have a header line stating the original file name and/or if the order of the input files matters (e.g. does it matter if `t_2.48/data.dat` values come after `t_10.48/data.dat` values).

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your suggestion, I do need the data to be stored in order and I edited the question. I think I can write a simple script with do loop to paste them in order and do the trick like your answer. But I think there maybe better way to sort them.

Comment: @EdMorton I have removed them.

Comment: @mqy Are the columns in the files space-delimited or tab-delimited?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ paste $(printf '%s\n' t_*/data.dat | sort -t'_' -k2,2n) |
     awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}'
-1.09822747e-03 -1.14092155e-03
-1.09833529e-03 -1.14131197e-03
-1.09844835e-03 -1.14171327e-03
-1.09856643e-03 -1.14212571e-03
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`cut`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) and
[`paste`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html):

```
paste <(cut -f2 file1) <(cut -f2 file2) ...
```

You can also generate and run the command in bash using a Perl one-liner like so:

```
perl -e '$cmd = join q{ }, q{paste}, map { "<(cut -f2 $_)" } @ARGV; system qq{bash -c "$cmd"};' file1 file2 ...
```